# PHP - How to design a secure photo gallery file structure

Tags: php, file, structure

I've decided not to use a BLOB to store the image for my gallery.  I've created a directory structure (with no DB transactions at all)... its pure file system.  For example i've created the following file structure:

http://www.mywebsite.com/Client_IMAGES/female/S/10f6f9b0d880ab3bd2c9c81fb33f8be59e09d9ed/MY_IMAGE.jpg

The folder is divided into male and female. The letter "S" being the first letter of the email address and the hash being unique to each user.  So if you can see what im doing is making a easy to search file structure.  My concern is on security.  I've updated my .htaccess file to include option-indexes which means no directories will be directly shown but is this the best way to be doing this ?  i see other sites using CGI and a photoID etc ..i need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the photos secure, I would suggest taking all of them out of your web root and possibly having a rewrite rule so that `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.png`, whatever are redirected to a script that does something like

```
$file = "/path/to/files/$_REQUEST[file]";
if (user_can_see($file)) {
   header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($file));
   readfile($file);
}
else {
   die("Hmm?");
}
```

Comment: sorry i should reword what im asking ...its not that i need the photos itself secure ...but what i need is to hide my directory structure ..i dont want the world seeing what my structure looks like ...for example you can tell from the link that i am organizing it by gender then by first letter of email then by some user hash ..i want to hide the characterisics of my directory structure.. thats why i think im gonig about this all the wrong way.  i am using codeigniter PHP framework btw.